# How can I make a logo background transparent?

Tags: css

Okay, so on my site, I have a logo, but it's image is set so that only the logo is there, but the rest of the image is transparent. I want to change the thing behind the logo so that you can see the background through everything but the actual logo. Basically, I want the thing behind the logo invisible.

My site is http://www.santarosasda.com/, the logo is at the top. Please help!

I am using the word press Risen theme.

I have tried:

```
#container-inner {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

People have told me to get rid of:

```
#container-inner {
        background: #fff;
    }
```

But since its a wordpress theme, this particular code is blocked from editting.

Any ideas?

Comment: It does Paul. The site is transparent

Comment: Your logo is already transparent, And what you want to put in background. Now its white ony

Answer (score 2):

Your `#container-inner` has a color (white) which is covering up your background image in the body.

On line 315 of [themes/risen/styles/light/styles.css](http://www.santarosasda.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/risen/styles/light/style.css?ver=1.1.1)

There is this code:

```
/* Container Inner */

#container-inner {

    /* Content Background */

    background: #fff;

}
```

Delete that block and it will work.

If you don't have access to that code (because it's in a Wordpress theme), then add a style sheet where you have control over the file like this:

```
#container-inner {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

That will help you override the style that is in a file out of your control. On my wordpress site I'd just add this under **Appearance** ➡ **Edit CSS**.

Comment: In style.css, there is no code "background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;"

Comment: with close to 3000 point's you should know better than to make duplicate answer's

Comment: @Number1son100 I updated the answer to make it more clear what the css looks like and added a link to the file so you can see it yourself.

Comment: I looked at that link, and compared it to the style sheet I am editting on wordpress, and they aren't the same. Seeing as I'm editting styles on wordpress, the stylesheet seems to be different. I still cant find that code.

Comment: @Number1son100 I updated the answer to show how you can override it on wordpress using the `!important` directive.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `background: #fff;` from `#container-inner`

Go [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Read the codex on how to create a child theme.

Then add `#container-inner{background:transparent!important;}`

Comment: Its in the wordpress theme, so I can't do that, its not in the code. I tried doing #container-inner {
    background: transparent !important;
}

Comment: You should add a Child theme then so you can properly edit the theme if it's a purchased theme that you don't want to edit the code of.

p.s. if you don't care about the theme updating you can just go straight into the stylesheet and remove it.